# Laravel 5.1 local server deployement

Tags: laravel-5

I have a project developed with laravel 5.1 and it successfully run on localhost:8000/. I want to make this project accessible by other users who are on the same network. Can any one help how to do this. I am using windows 10 currently.

Comment: check you IP by taping ipconfig on cmd and the the other hit `192.162.2.5:8000/` for example if your ip is `192.162.2.5`

Comment: thanx it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you check your IP address of network then
for example, we consider IP = 192.162.2.5
now you check open you site passing url = 192.162.2.5:8000 or 192.162.2.5

if site not open then --
try the following command on cmd
**method 1**
`php artisan serve --host 192.162.2.5 --port 80`
now  you open browser and pass URL = your IP (192.162.2.5)

**method 2**
if you want to your site run on port 8000
then run following command
`php artisan serve --host 192.162.2.5 --port 8000`
now  you open browser and pass URL = your IP (192.162.2.5)